# Split address string with carriage returns

Tags: sql, string

I have an address field where all the address details are held in one column, I want to create some labels so need to be able to split the address into the correct postal format.

> Example of the data I have:
>
> Address Column: 1 somehwere Road Town County Postcode
>
> I would like to get the address in this format so the address is split
>   into columns:
>
> Address1 Column: 1 Somewhere Road
>
> Address2 Column: Town
>
> Address3 Column: County
>
> Address4 Column: Postcode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think ive figured it out, I need to use the below sort of query to find the carriage return and then use left and right queries to find the part of the address I want, this is the first part and gives me the road details out of the address

```
left(Address, (CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), Address, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), Address)))) as 'Address1'
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to refer to procedure language included into RDBMS you use. There is no way to do this in pure SQL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x